# Windows delete old backups

Tags: windows-10, windows-backup

I have an external HD where 3 different system image backups by windows were created in some other laptop. Now I have a different PC and I want to free disk space by deleting 2 of 3 backups. All searches in web show that I can use

Control Panel > Windows 7 Restore and Backup > Manage Space

But however, this does not have a "manage space" button, and even when enabling backup no disk space can be freed (since I think the backup was created by another PC).

Please help, thanks

Comment: What's stopping you from deleting everything, or, if required, formatting the disk?

Comment: @harrymc I need a single backup on desk (latest), and others not needed

Comment: Why not delete the files via Explorer?

Comment: From explorer I can see only a single file with size (200 GB). However, disk used space is more than (2 TB). All files (hidden, system) are shown, and their total size does not seem to reach more than 700 GB